# In C++11, can you declare global variables and function prototypes on the same line?

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11

While I was writing some C++11 code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int a, b, array[25];
int function();

int main() {
... (not important)
```

out of curiosity, I put the variable declarations in the same line as the function prototype:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int function(), a, b, array[25];

int main() {
... (not important)
```

It compiled properly on XCode (set to [-std=c++11]) and  `a, b, array[]` could be used like normal variables/arrays.

Will this work across most/all compilers, and is this discouraged/fine? Why does this work in C++ (function prototypes and variable declarations seem quite different...)

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Yes, but don't :-)

Comment: I would already discourage declaration/definition of several variables on the same line (even worst when they don't have the exact same types)...

Comment: Those variables are nothing but global variables. Therefore, they can be used thought out the code, but it's not recommended (use local variables instead).

Comment: That looks really scary.

Comment: Have you any idea why this would work? Function prototyping and variable declaration seems very different...

Comment: @RyanJonZhang: Not really that different. A "function prototype" is just a function declaration. Functions and variables share two important properties: they have a name and a type. Those are both part of a declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The declaration says that `function(x)`, `a`, `b`, and `array[i]` are all `int`s.
(This is the "old-school reading" of types - it always works in C, but C++ broke it; `int *x` can be read "`*x` is an `int`", but `int &x` can't be read "`&x` is an `int`".)

This has been fine since the early days of C (so, for half a century or so), and it's not limited to global declarations.

It's also very confusing, and you will not find many who think it's a good idea.
Most people have now given up on declaring more than one variable in a line.
It's less readable, easy to forget an initializer, and screens are capable of displaying many lines simultaneously these days.

Comment: ... and while it may be seen as a limit of the tools used, it often makes merging code changes harder.